# Tune SSH for bad connections

Tags: wireless-networking, ssh, ip

What options can be used on Linux' OpenSSH Server and the `ssh` command itself (or their config files) to make ssh most reliable on flaky connections (eg. long distance WiFi)?

Is it useful to tune the ssh configuration, or are there better options tuning Linux TCP parameters?

Comment: There really needs to be an answer to this. Using something other than SSH (like mosh) is not an option for most people.

Answer (score 2):

[Mosh](https://mosh.org/) is a replacement for SSH. It's more robust and responsive, especially over Wi-Fi, cellular, and long-distance links.

Comment: As mosh is an replacement, it is not always available nor installed by default. So I just wonder what can be done by tuning OpenSSH.

Comment: Also it seems mosh won't support "popular" ssh options, like `-L` and `-R` tunneling, and as such won't replace SSH as used by other tools. It may however support basic usage, eg. as of `rsync`, one have to try out...

Comment: While I always appreciate other options, I'm getting tired of hearing `mosh`, which is incompatible with `ssh`, as the solution. Somewhere we need to have a discussion about the [configuration options](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5) for `ssh` without having the subject changed. Not your fault. But notice how as of right now there are no on-topic answers. So is the case with all Google results.

Answer (score 0):

I've had fantastic luck with autossh* and tmux when working over troublesome connections. Something like this:

```
autossh remotehost -t tmux att -t session-name
```

http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/

Answer (score -1):

I realize this is an old question.  I use mosh mostly but sometimes I like to have gvim working remotely.

I have not tried this yet
http://blogs.perl.org/users/smylers/2011/08/ssh-productivity-tips.html
specifically the section on Resilient Connections

Comment: “I have not tried this yet” so why do you propose it?